# Align bottom center a text inside a Container of stack

Tags: flutter

It's the first time I use Flutter and I'm having some problem aligning containers.

Here is my code:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return const MyItem(
      imgSrc: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610655012457-9cbd66fe510b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=80',
      text: 'Lorem ipsum');
}

class MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.imgSrc,
      required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  final String imgSrc;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 3)),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3)),
            child: Image.network(imgSrc, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 3)),
            child: Text(
              text.toUpperCase(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

But I want the text `lorem ipsum` at the bottom side, not near the top side.
Seems like `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter` doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

You just have to wrap the container widget with the **Positioned** widget, just tell the **bottom: 0,**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyItem ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      final imgSrc =
          'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1610655012457-9cbd66fe510b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2940&q=80';
      final String text = 'Lorem ipsum';
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          decoration:
              BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 3)),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3)),
                child: Image.network(imgSrc, fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ),
              Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Container(
                  height: 50,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 3),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    '$text'.toUpperCase(),
                    //text.toUpperCase(),
                    style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is awesome! you just saved my night.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Align` widget. with assign value to the `alignment` attribute the container will expand to fill its parent and position its child within itself according to the given value.

here is the sample :

```dart
class MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyItem(
      {Key? key,
      required this.imgSrc,
      required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  final String imgSrc;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 3)),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
        child: Stack(children: [
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3)),
            child: Image.network(imgSrc, fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
       Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child:Container(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 3)),
            child: Text(
              text.toUpperCase(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),),
        ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work, i think `child:` is missing and anyway the text is still on the top

Answer (score 0):

You also can use below codes

```
class MyItem extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyItem({Key? key, required this.imgSrc, required this.text})
      : super(key: key);

  final String imgSrc;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration:
            BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 3)),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(
                    imgSrc,
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3)),
          child: Container(
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 3)),
            child: Text(
              text.toUpperCase(),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must fix the height and width of Stack as it is like a graph, where the centre is (0,0). There x & y has a value from -1 to 1 in the container. You go up from the centre value goes nearer to -1 and down +1 same as If you go left -1 right +1.

After that, you can use AlignmentDirectional to tell where exactly you want to put chid of the stack. in your case as below.

Align(
alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
child: SizedBox()....

==Now coming to your code must be like this... review comments in the same too.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
      //Master container size of mobile screen and limits of stack.
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.purple, width: 3),
      ),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 3),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
            child: Container(
              width:
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1, //You can fix your own
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.blueAccent, width: 3),
              ),
              child: Image.network(imgSrc, fit: BoxFit.cover),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: const AlignmentDirectional(0, 1),
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1,
              //You can fix your own
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
              /*alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,*/
              //This will only work inside of container.
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.orange, width: 3),
              ),
              child: Text(
                text.toUpperCase(),
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 14.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```